# getting error when i work on repo in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target
>   [App\Repositories\FaultTypes\FaultTypesInterface] is not instantiable
>   while building [App\Http\Controllers\FaultTypesController,
>   App\Services\FaultTypesService].

Comment: please help me out  when i am creating repository and working with then give me error. and is[
"Target [App\Repositories\FaultTypes\FaultTypesInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\FaultTypesController, App\Services\FaultTypesS ▶"]

Comment: Could you add your code to the question? Could you explain what your are exactly trying to do? And what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You have probably something like this in your controller

```
public function __construct(FaultTypesInterface $faultTypes) {
...
}
```

Problem is that Laravel's Service Container dosn't know how to instantiate such an interface

You can solve this by declaring this binding. So in `app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in the `register()` method you can write something like this

```
app()->bind('App\Repositories\FaultTypes\FaultTypesInterface', 'Path\To\Your\Concrete\Class');
```

Comment: same problem are repeat again

Comment: I am sorry, but with the information you provided, this is the best help I could provide.